# Homebrewing Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**Note:** This evaluation will close on **10 October 2012**. Please get your comments in by then!

Comment: So, is this a new robot?   Is this a prelude to something happening with the site in general?   I ask because we did this in July.

Comment: @baka Nope! You guys get these periodically -- specifically, once a quarter/every three months. They're a good way for y'all to keep track of your progress and to ensure you're staying on track. :)

Comment: I've been busy with work and other life things, and have not had a chance to even look at these questions, much less think about them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

[When is the most critical time to control fermentation temperature?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7469/when-is-the-most-critical-time-to-control-fermentation-temperature)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Nice question..

Answer (score 2):

[Can Olive Oil REPLACE oxygenating wort](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/can-olive-oil-replace-oxygenating-wort)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I like this question & answers

Answer (score 1):

[Is there any trick to draining the water out of an immersion chiller?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7464/is-there-any-trick-to-draining-the-water-out-of-an-immersion-chiller)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[What is the purpose of stepping up a starter](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/what-is-the-purpose-of-stepping-up-a-starter)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

[Why did fermentation take so long to start?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/why-did-fermentation-take-so-long-to-start)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: A very typical question good comforting answers

Answer (score 0):

[Can lowering temperature too rapidly result in stuck fermentation?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7476/can-lowering-temperature-too-rapidly-result-in-stuck-fermentation)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[What causes fermentation to slow down under normal conditions?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/what-causes-fermentation-to-slow-down-under-normal-conditions)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 0):

[Is there any danger in fermenting outside?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7491/is-there-any-danger-in-fermenting-outside)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score -2):

[Good Brewing Chemistry Books](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7448/good-brewing-chemistry-books)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: We try to typically discourage poll questions

Answer (score -2):

[Coffee Beans for Homebrewing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7474/coffee-beans-for-homebrewing)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Since this question is asking about what kind of beans, it feels pretty subjective to me.